# Not able to install the RYU controller

Tags: ryu

I have tried to install the RYU controller .
I am using the below commands “sudo python setup.py install “ its error out with below message 
That ryu.hooks not available and when I run the command “python setup.py install” it gives the error that setuptools not available .

Please give the response as soon as possible we are in the middle of installing the controller .

-Ajay

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing the controller in a Linux-based VM? If so, then SDN Hub (http://sdnhub.org/resources/) offers a vm with Ryu already installed. You may consider downloading and using it. Depending on your familiarity with Ryu, you may also want to use the [Ryuretic](https://github.com/Ryuretic/RyureticLabs/wiki) framework for implementing your project. The linked lab provides instructions for getting it up and running.

Comment: Hello Jacob , do you also have the OVF is compatible for vmware esxi 5.5 .

Comment: @Ajay. I don't know about that specific version of vmware, but the instructions on SDNhub.org indicate that it can be run with vmware: "Import the OVA (i.e., SDN Hub Tutorial VM) into Virtualbox or VMware Player and boot it. "  Here's a link to the download page: http://sdnhub.org/tutorials/sdn-tutorial-vm/. Personally, I use the OVA with virtualbox, and I haven't had any issues. I haven't used OVA with VMware player yet.

Comment: We need GUI or putty can also be used ?